# Drawing a square using glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLES

Tags: opengl, c++, polygon, drawing

I used a version of the following code to draw a triangle using glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLES, per Anton Gerdelan's very nice tutorial here:

[Hello Triangle !](https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html)

It draws a nice triangle.

I have modified the code as explained in the code comments below, attempting to use glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLES to draw two triangles, making a square, as suggested in the section "Experimenting" on the webpage, but it still just gives the same triangle, even though I added 3 more vertices to the triangle_vertices array, doubled the size of the data in the glBufferData command, and replaced glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3) by glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6).

Why is that ?

By using GL_TRIANGLE_FAN I have succeeded in drawing the square I want (actually a rectangle because of the aspect ratio), but I would like to be able to get the same result using GL_TRIANGLES. I also don't want to use any alternative to glDrawArrays, even though I know that options are available that allow clever re-use of vertex data, when distinct triangles share common vertices.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"
#define GLFW_DLL
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("Hello world !\n");

    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(2048, 1536, "Hello !", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum ret = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != ret)
    {
        // Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    // One triangle:
    //float triangle_vertices[] = {
    //-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top left point
    //0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top right point
    //0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right point
    //};

    // Two triangles:
    float triangle_vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top left point
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top right point
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right point
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right point
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f // bottom left point
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top left point
    };

    GLuint vertex_buffer_object = 0; // VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer_object);
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_object);

        //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * 3, triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // The previous command was for drawing a triangle, while the following one is intended for 
        // drawing a square, although it doesn't yet work !
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * 6, triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbind
    }

    GLuint vertex_array_object = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // enable the first input variable (vertex position)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_object);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }


    GLuint shader_program_object = 0;
    { // SHADERS

        const char* vertex_shader_str =
            "#version 410\n"
            "in vec3 a_position;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
            "gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);\n"
            "}";

        const char* fragment_shader_str =
            "#version 410\n"
            "out vec4 o_frag_colour;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
            "o_frag_colour = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);\n"
            "}\n";

        GLuint vertex_shader_object = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex_shader_object, 1, &vertex_shader_str, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader_object);

        GLuint fragment_shader_object = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader_object, 1, &fragment_shader_str, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader_object);

        shader_program_object = glCreateProgram();
        glBindAttribLocation(shader_program_object, 0, "a_position");

        glAttachShader(shader_program_object, vertex_shader_object);
        glAttachShader(shader_program_object, fragment_shader_object);
        glLinkProgram(shader_program_object);

    }

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader_program_object);
        {
            glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
            {
                //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            }
            glBindVertexArray(0);
        }
        glUseProgram(0);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh !!! It was simply a typo ! A missing comma at the end of the line

```
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f // bottom left point
```

What a relief !

Comment: Thanks ! Will do asap. Must wait until tomorrow because privileges low :)